# Sign up (guest checkout) issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, registration, guest-checkout

I have added `customer_register_succes` event for guest customer account creation during guest checkout.
After the successful order when the user sign up by my event and observers call in which I load order for that guest user.

I have added event and observer for sign up and login of customer

```
<event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer instance="YX\Customer\Observer\RegisterSuccess" name="customer_register_succes"/>
</event>

<event name="customer_login">
    <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="YX\Customer\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
</event>
```

`Observer code`

```
 class RegisterSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{ 

protected  $customlogger;
protected  $tempblock;
protected  $customerHelper;
protected $_blockFactory;


public function __construct(
    \YX\Catalog\Block\OrderHelper $orderHelper,
    \YX\Customer\Helper\CustomerHelper $customerHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory

)
{
    $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->tempblock = $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('YX\Catalog\Block\OrderHelper');
    $this->customerHelper = $customerHelper;

}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    if (!($this->customerHelper->isCustomer())){

        $customerID = $this->customerHelper->getCustomerId();
        $orderId = $this->customerHelper->getOrderId();
        $this->tempblock->guestToCustomer($orderId,$customerID);

    }
  }
}
```

> getCustomerId function

```
 public function getCustomerId(){
    $customerId =  $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    return $customerId;
}
```

> getOrderId function

```
 public  function  getOrderId() {

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();

    $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

    if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer_email = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        $order_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', 1);

        foreach ($order_collection as $data){
            $order = $data->getEntityId();
            return $order;
        }
    }
}
```

> guestToCustomer function

```
public function guestToCustomer($incrementId,$customerId)
{

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface')->get($incrementId);

 if ($order->getId() && !$order->getCustomerId()) {
     $order->setCustomerId($customerId);
     $order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
     $this->orderRepository->save($order);
  }
 }
```

I am getting this error

`An ID is needed. Set the ID and try again.`

[image]

I am not able to figure out what's happening, and when I login with the just created account I can see my orders as I have events and observer for login also.

It works for login, not for sign up process.
and after this, the first time user(new user) sign up process gives me same error.

Despite that error I even check the `customer_entity` table and it has customer entry.

`select  * from customer_entity order by  created_at desc limit 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your observer class by following class and modify namespace:

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;

class CustomerRegisterSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;

    /**
     * @var OrderRepository
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * CustomerRegisterSuccess constructor.
     *
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
     * @param OrderRepository $orderRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory,
        OrderRepository $orderRepository
    ) {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $orderCollection = $this->getOrderCollection($customer->getEmail());
        foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
            if ($order->getEntityId() && !$order->getCustomerId()) {
                $order->setCustomerId($customerId);
                $order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
                $this->orderRepository->save($order);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $customerEmail
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface[]
     */
    private function getOrderCollection($customerEmail)
    {
        /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
        $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
        $searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('customer_email', $customerEmail)
            ->addFilter('customer_is_guest', 1);

        return $this->orderRepository
            ->getList($searchCriteriaBuilder->create())
            ->getItems();
    }
}
```